# UBIFS boot error

Tags: filesystems, embedded-linux, bootloader, ubifs

I have a SAM9 based board running embedded linux.

I had a JFFS2 file system and now thinking of moving to UBIFS.

I enabled UBIFS as target file system in make menuconfig of buildroot package which I'm using for my board.

I generated the rootfs.arm.ubifs file which I flashed on my board using nandwrite utility of bootloader the same way which I was using for .jffs2 file.

I also changed the bootargs to :

`setenv bootargs 'console=ttyS0,115200 rw ubi.mtd=1,2048 rootfstype=ubifs root=ubi0:rootfs'`

But I'm getting the following error which booting the board :

```
Creating 2 MTD partitions on "atmel_nand":                                                                                                       
0x000000000000-0x000000400000 : "Kernel"                                                                                                         
0x000000400000-0x000010000000 : "Data"                                                                                                           
UBI: attaching mtd1 to ubi0                                                                                                                      
UBI: physical eraseblock size:   131072 bytes (128 KiB)                                                                                          
UBI: logical eraseblock size:    126976 bytes                                                                                                    
UBI: smallest flash I/O unit:    2048                                                                                                            
UBI: sub-page size:              512                                                                                                             
UBI: VID header offset:          2048 (aligned 2048)                                                                                             
UBI: data offset:                4096                                                                                                            
UBI warning: ubi_scan: 276 PEBs are corrupted                                                                                                    
corrupted PEBs are: 0 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 517
UBI error: ubi_read_volume_table: the layout volume was not found                                                                                
UBI error: ubi_init: cannot attach mtd1                                                                                                          
UBI error: ubi_init: UBI error: cannot initialize UBI, error -22
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a guess, but did you *ubinize* your rootfs before flashing it onto the raw NAND?

From http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/doc/ubifs.html#L_usptools

```
The images produced by mkfs.ubifs may be written to UBI volumes using 
ubiupdatevol or may be further fed to the ubinize tool to create an UBI 
image which may be put to the raw flash.
```

Comment: Thanks ! That worked :) ... I ubinized the rootfs and flashed it to NAND and it worked.